# Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Working fin for all calendar except one

Tags: request, calendar

I am using the PHP Google calendar API V3 since 2016. It is working fine. I am using the same code with different calendars from the same account. It is working with all calendar except one that suddenly stop working returning the error “Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup”. The other calendars still working perfectly. The number of request for this month is about 100 request only. 
Do you have any suggestion why it is working for all calendar except one?
Thanks

Comment: You probably exceeded your request limit, or are not signed in correctly, judging by the error.

Comment: I have not exceeded your request limit because I just have 100 requests. And it still working for other calendar.